# Deploy automático com git não funciona na locaweb

Tags: git, deploy

Boa noite pessoal!
Estou tentando fazer um deploy automático com o git diretamente no servidor do site na locaweb, porém o mesmo não funciona. Segui diversos tutoriais, mas não consegui, consigo enviar os arquivos para o repositório que criei na locaweb, mas quando vou verificar se os arquivos foram para a pasta public_html, ela aparece do mesmo modo que deixei.

o conteúdo do arquivo post-receive é este:

```
#!/bin/sh/
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/storage/x/xx/xx/sitexxxxxxxx/public_html git checkout -f
```

Estou configurando de maneira errada?

Agradeço de qualquer forma

Comment: O repositório é da própria Locaweb? O que acontece?

Comment: Olá @RodrigoRigotti, acredito que o problema não era da Locaweb, e depois de vários testes, consegui resolver o problema que descrevo a seguir:

Comment: Estava criando o arquivo de post-receive pelo windows e enviando por ftp/sftp, e depois, executava o chmod e deste modo não funcionava, tudo funcionou depois que creiei o arquivo pelo proprio servidor com o vi. depois executei o chmod e tudo funcionou. Quando vi alguns tutoriais na internet e testei os mesmos não fazia idéia de que isso influenciaria. Um outro detalhe, é que o path que utilizei foi GIT_WORK_TREE=~/public_html e funcionou de modo perfeito. Espero que isso possa auxiliar quem por ventura passar pelo mesmo tipo de problema que eu passei.